# Define ring and field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

An algebraic ring and field are defined by two inner binary operations. I am only unsure about one thing: do the operators have to be plus and times or are they arbitrary? Almost every book (and Wikipedia) only use plus and times. However, I find this restriction somewhat untypical, because one does not make this restriction when defining the group.

Comment: Ususally, they are *denoted by* $+$ and $\cdot$ (or $\times$), and the neutral element for $+$ is called $0$, and the neutral element for $\cdot$ is called $1$. Sometrimes a ${}_R$ indicates the ring which the operation belongs to. But of course it's not always the same "plus" or "times" for all rings. For instance, you could define a ring operation on the subsets of a set by setting $\cdot=\cap$ (binary intersection) and $+=\Delta$ (symmetric difference).

Comment: Using symbols $+$ and $\times$ is purely a notation. It does not have any mathematical content. But it is pretty rare to see other notations.

Comment: When defined in a group it is not specified because it can be both. That is, you can have an additive or a multiplicative group.

Comment: @Gae.S. I think you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: But in fact there are other operations that can be defined on some set G such that G is a group or a ring.

Answer (score 1):

They certainly do not have to be anything that one would otherwise call multiplication and addition, but they have to satisfy certain algebraic laws that are also satisfied by ordinary multiplication and addition, and in the context of the theories of rings and fields one calls them multiplication and addition.

For example, the operation of intersection of sets in the role of multiplication, and symmetric difference of sets in the role of addition, makes the set of all subsets of a particular set into a ring.